# When to use object and when to use class in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a service object called MyService with functions defined that are used by my Play application's controllers. One particular function in MyService is parsing some text, and turning it into a JSON object. So my process will be:

- Parse some text containing unstructured book info (title, author etc) into some Scala objects (Book objects)
- Convert the Book objects into JSON format
- Return the JSON

What I am wondering is, in the step where I parse the text and create my Scala objects, how should I define them? If this was Java I would just have an inner class named 'Book', but with Scala I don't know whether I should define an inner object or inner class inside my MyService object, and I don't know why/when I would choose one over the other.

Could someone explain when to use an object and when to use a class?

Comment: This question has been sitting as "unanswered" for a long time. Do either of these answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

You use `object` when you only want **EXACTLY ONE** instance of your class.
`objects` can't have parameters and it's methods and values can be accessed via `MyObject.myMethod`.

In Java you would use the singleton pattern to achieve what `object` is in Scala.
Then you would have something like `MyObject.getInstance().myMethod`.

In your case you want to parse information into a class. I would make the parser class an `object` (assuming the parsing process is static).
The result however is not static, since it relies on the parsed data. Book should definitly be a class. (If there is exactly one Book, the parsing would not make much sense, would it?)

Answer (score 0):

@Kigyo's answer is fine, but there's something else that should be addressed here. You're working within an MVC framework, and this `Book` you're describing sounds exactly like a **model**. This `MyService` object you describe is starting to sound like it's very bloated, and serializing a `Book` as JSON is something you can do entirely within a Play model.

```
package models

import play.api.libs.json._

case class Book(title: String, author: String, pages: Int)

object Book {

    /** Use one of Play's json macros to define an implicit serializer/deserializer */
    implicit val jsonFormat: Format[Book] = Json.format[Book]

    def parse(rawText: String): Book = {
        // Move your book parsing logic to here and construct the new Book instance.
    }

}
```

Then in your controller function you would do something like:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val rawText: String = ... // The raw text you're parsing the book data from.
val book: Book = Book.parse(rawText) // The parsed Book
val json: JsValue = Json.toJson(book) // The Book as a Play JSON object (can be returned as a JSON response)
val jsonString: String = Json.stringify(json) // The Book JSON as a String object, in case you need that..
```

This is a little more verbose than it needs to be, but I separated it out line-by-line to illustrate what's happening at each step. If all you wanted was the JSON as a string `Jsons.stringify(Json.toJson(Book.parse(rawText)))` would suffice.

Now the `Book` logic is self-contained, and not cluttering up another object.